# Resharpe.portable get Twitter request token

Tags: xamarin, twitter-oauth

Hello i'm doing an xamarin.form application and i'm implementing the twitter login using oauth.
I have problem to get the request_token folowing the link:
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token

using restsharp.portable for the request POST i arrive at this point:

```
public async void GetTwitterToken()
        {
            try
            {
                TwitterLogin tw = new TwitterLogin();
                RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com");
                RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/oauth/request_token", Method.POST);
                client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(tw.oauth_consumer_key, tw.oauth_consumer_secret);
                IRestResponse response = await client.Execute(request);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Parameter "response" it's ok but i'don't know how to parse to get token (it's not json).

i have seen this example:

```
public void GetRequestToken()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com"); // Note NO /1

    client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(
        _consumerKey, 
        _consumerSecret, 
        "http://markashleybell.com" // Value for the oauth_callback parameter
    );

    var request = new RestRequest("/oauth/request_token", Method.POST);
    var response = client.Execute(request);

    var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);

    _token = qs["oauth_token"];
    _tokenSecret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];
}
```

But i don't have HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content) whith xamarin.form framework